# How to delay CSS and Script loading after JS has executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, backbone.js

I have a backbone.js app, my problem is that there are some slow loading files (a .css and a .js) which blocks the page loading until they are fully loaded.

I would like to find a way to delay those loadings AFTER the backbone view is rendered, so after some JS has been executed. I have done this in JS:

```
view.render()
$('head').append("<script type=...")
$('head').append("<link rel='stylesheet'...")
```

This works, but since I have loaded my CSS like this (it is a webfont css) my page fonts are hidden in android phones, and they show up only when i touch the screen.

Is that a bad way of loading css and JS after page load ? Is there a better way ?

Answer (score 0):

You can conditionally include a script file in JavaScript

```
if(someConditionIsTrue){
    // load script from the server
    $.getScript( "somePath/onTheServer/script.js", function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
        // do something after the load is complete
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The real question here is why are your JavaScript and CSS files slow loading? Is it because they contain a lot of code, or reference files on external sites that take time to load? If you can refactor these to speed up their loading then of course the best action would be to load them in the `<head>` of your page.

You could try splitting your stylesheet into two parts, with the webfont declarations etc in a small CSS file that you load at the top of the page, and extra optional CSS rules in a second file that is loaded after the page is rendered.

**However**, I would recommend that you don't load CSS rules after the page is rendered, for the simple reason that it may mean that elements in the page are moved around if you have defined positions or sizes in your CSS rules. It is always best practice for the CSS to the loaded before the page is rendered, so that users don't see bits and pieces moving around as the browser loads, parses and renders your CSS rules.

Comment: I agree for best practices, and for the changes I should make to speed  up those loadings. The weird thing here is that the two files which loads slowly (very slowly) are google maps JS and google webfonts CSS. They load at a normal rate on any device apart from android phones : on android they take minutes to load, often going timeout. By loading them by injecting them in HEAD with JS thought, they load instantly

Comment: OK so I don't have any Android devices to test but that does sound weird. In any case, I think splitting up the files may be the way forward.

Comment: I ended up replacing gmaps by openstreetmaps and injecting the google fonts CSS content in a <style> tag. dirty but works. no idea yet for the google.com hosted files on android (4.0+ only btw)

Answer (score 0):

The css load in an async manner so the issue is really the js.
First you should have it on the bottom of your page, but you really need to have on the head of on the body, to stop it from blocking rendering add an async attribute to it:

< script type="text/javascript" async src="your path">< /script>
If you have multiple files that depend on each other, you can do it with 
< script type="text/javascript" async defer src="your path">< /script>
< script type="text/javascript" async defer src="your path">< /script>
This will execute the async files in order after it loads.
You can read more in here:
http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#attr-script-async